# Get Jenkins Systemtime using Rest (JSON)

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to get the system time (say as long-timestamp) of a Jenkins deploy using the Rest API. In my case I was looking at JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing else, every HTTP response should have a `Date` header which will be the server-side time.  You wouldn't need any authentication for this, a simple HEAD request for the homepage would do the job.